# Do axioms in knowledge base joined by 'AND'?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

Do axioms in knowledge base joined by 'AND'?
For example, if 'A and B' is one of the axioms, can I just put {A,B} in my knowledge base, as they will be implied with 'AND' relation among them in the knowledge base anyway? Thanks.

Comment: There is too much debauchery or frivolity to put downvotes. It seems that we are reaching the situation where every time someone does not understand an intelligent question, they happily and with impunity put a downvote without bothering to explain why they put it.

Comment: @Piquito thanks for your kindness. I'm equally confused. If my whole concept is wrong, then probably better it's being pointed out directly. I performed my due diligence in researching. Just that I cannot identify the answers and I guess it would probably to the interest of the public if I open up a question like this.

Comment: With all deliberation, I have not put the upvote that has deleted the downvote that someone had put. We have to be glad of the conscientious person who has put it. Regards.

Comment: Thanks, @Piquito. I downvote rarely, but whenever I do, I explain why I’ve done so.

Comment: @Lubin, As it should be but unfortunately it is not. You are a respectable user and I have seen your contributions to MSE many times. Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

Note that a knowledge base is an ordered pair containing a [TBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tbox) and an [ABox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abox). If you'd like to add the axiom $A\land B$ to the knowledge base, then simply add the axiom to the finite set of assertion components or the ABox, for the respective knowledge base.